# Android: Passing parameter to Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, methods, parameters

I'm trying to learn Android programming and so far so good. Right now I'm trying to learn something about threads but i cant get my code to work.

I already read

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#concurrency_handler

I tried to use both to make my code work but i have no idea how to do so since none of them fit my needs and both use the same example of a progress bar.

I have 3 buttons in my layout that i want to move (slowly) up or down. I wanted to do this with a thread since the mainUI activity should not stop working while doing this.
So my idea was to start a new thread where i wait for a little time and than set the parameters, and i do this again and again.

I probably could solve it with global variables, but i dont want to use such a "cheap" trick for something like this.

My code looks like this (Most of it copied from the two sides since i cant find a working example for a thread in which parameters are given to Methods)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 // Need handler for callbacks to the UI thread
final Handler mHandler = new Handler();

// Create runnable for posting
final Runnable mUpdateResults = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        updateResultsInUi();
    }
};

protected void moveMenu(int direction, final int time) {

    // Fire off a thread to do some work that we shouldn't do directly in the UI thread
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                doSomethingExpensive(time);
                mHandler.post(mUpdateResults);   // <--- Here im looking for a way to give i to the updateResultsInUi() Method
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

private void updateResultsInUi(int i) {

    // Back in the UI thread -- update our UI elements based on the data in mResults
    ScrollView topScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    LinearLayout botLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayoutButton);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsScrollView = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,90+i);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams paramsLinearLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,0,10-i);
    topScrollView.setLayoutParams(paramsScrollView);
    botLinearLayout.setLayoutParams(paramsLinearLayout);
}

// Simulating something timeconsuming
private void doSomethingExpensive(int time) {
  try {
    Thread.sleep(time);
  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

public void button_click_del(View v)
{
    [...]
    moveMenu(direction, time);
}

[...]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new runnable on the go:

```
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                doSomethingExpensive(time);
                final int finalI = i;
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        updateResultsInUi(finalI);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to pass values to the thread. The approach I follow is:

Create a new class that will extend the `runnable` class.

```
public interface myRunnable extends Runnable {

  public void setParams(int param1, int param2);
 }
```

now implement this class

```
public class ImplementMyRunnable implements myRunnable{
int param1;
int param2;
  public void setParams(int param1, int param2){
     this.param1 = param1;
     this.param2 = param2;
  }

 public void run(){
    //your code here and use as many parameters you want
 }
}
```

now in your moveMenu function

```
protected void moveMenu(int direction, final int time) {
   ImplementMyRunnable object1 = new ImplementMyRunnable();
   object1.setParams(1,12);
   Thread myThread = new Thread(object1);
   myThread.start();
}
```

basically what i wanted to point here is. Create a new class that extends the `Runnable` class and add what ever functionality you want now or you may require in future. Pass as many parameters as you want in `constructor` or in any other setter function.

This is a more neat approach and will help you to extend your code more easily and cleanly in future.

The code syntax might be wrong. I only wanted to share the approach. Hope it will help.

Comment: with some modifications I made it work on all of my Runnables. Thanks for the code